# python take screenshot of specific window but "when minimize"

Tags: python, screenshot

i can take screenshot of specific window but it has some problems. if you minimize you can't take screenshot or if you put other window over our window what i'll screenshot...

let me see.

```
import pygetwindow
import time
import pyautogui
import PIL




while 1:
    # also able to edit z3 to specified window-title string like: "Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)"
    
    #first find window

    my = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('MyGame')[0] 
    # quarter of screen screensize
    


    x3 = my.width
    y3 = my.height 

    # top-left
    my.moveTo(0, 0) # move window 0 to 0

    # save screenshot
    p = pyautogui.screenshot() 
    p.save(r'result.png') 

    # edit screenshot
    im = PIL.Image.open('result.png')
    im_crop = im.crop((0, 0, x3, (y3)))
    im_crop.save('result.png', quality=100)
```

if you execute this codes it will work but i want i can screenshot when window unseen or minimized...

please help me for library i am beginner.

Thanks for you all :) Have a good day...